# Retrieve JSON Object and Store Values in Django

Tags: database, django, json, admin

I want to retrieve a JSON object from an external API, read it's values, and store it in my database. The issue I'm having is figuring out where to put the code. Ideally, I would want to do this from the admin interface. It's something that only me as an admin should be able to do . I can code the view for retrieving, reading, and saving the data, but I'm at a loss as to how I'd make this available from the admin interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the view as you describe and use something like https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites to hook it in to the admin structure.

There may be a better way, but when I've done this in the past, I've also then customized the default admin index.html template to link to my custom admin view.